# TableServiceContext.SaveChanges() fails

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am looking for pointers to why the above method would fail.

In my TableServiceContext subclass I have:

```
   public void AddDevice(Device d)
    {
        d.PartitionKey = "A";
        d.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.AddObject("Devices", d);
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The call to `SaveChanges()` fails with a very generic message to diagnostics:

```
An error occurred while processing this request.. Stack:    at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
   at WorkerRole1.DeviceServiceContext.AddDevice(Device d) in DeviceServiceContext.cs:line 30
```

Any ideas what could be amiss?
The Devices table exists. The storage account exists and seems ok.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tracing and head scratching, it turns out that the SaveChanges() method was unhappy about one of the properties in my entity object. The inner exception spoke about "method not implemented". Fixed but a more precise exception message would have been nice...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the Device class is not serializable.

The exception could be caused by several things, see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/chanderdhall/archive/2010/07/10/dataservicerequestexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-an-error-occurred-while-processing-this-request.aspx) blog post for some examples.

Comment: Thanks! I decorated Device with [DataContract] and [DataMember] to be certain. Still same result. Some digging reveals that this.SaveChanges throws a DataServiceRequestException. The BatchStatusCode contained in there is -1 which doesn't make sense (it's supposed to an http code?).

Comment: Interesting that Azure would get upset about CamelCase. That's not my issue though, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Azure, but I've been told that Azure does NOT admit UpperCase in Blob, Queues or Table names... 
Maybe the problem is not the object or the method, but the Tablename since it's called "Devices" instead "devices"...
But I'm not sure... Hope this will help.